# Choose proper Timestampformat when using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-time, datetime-parsing, datetimeformatter

I am using `DateTimeFormatter` in my code for parsing the timestamp.
I have timestamp like `01-JAN-21 10.10.10.100000 AM` and looking at this website
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html
I tried with the pattern: `dd-LLL-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a` which isn't working. I get `illegal pattern component "LLL"`. I also tried with `dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a` but the data isn't parsed.

How should the pattern look like?

Comment: which type of Date you want to generate from your Timestamp?
it can be Date, LocalDateTime, LocalDate...

Comment: What would it be the difference by Date and LocalDate?

Comment: you can find your answer about differences between Date and LocalDate here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60144827/difference-between-java-util-date-and-java-time-localdate-in-java

Comment: What is your suggestion for a timestampformat in case I want to generate "Date" and in case I want to generate "LocalDate"?

Comment: take a look at this answer, it is a complete answer and I think you can solve your issue with this, also a bit creativity is needed, update me if you could not solve your issue with this one, i can help you more, GL:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/7189597

Comment: The second pattern, `dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a`, looks right to me. A [mre] will help us find out what’s wrong. Remember to specify exactly what goes wrong. Paste any error message that you see into your question.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Use `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). A `LocalDate` can hold only the date part. For a timestamp I assume you also need the time-of-day part, therefore `LocalDateTime`.